# A different label for each iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in the following code, I want to assign a different label to the text field for each iteration.

```
<%= f.field_for :skills do |s|  %>
    <li>
      <label>Skills</label>
      <%= s.text_field :name %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

How can I do that?
Here is my controller code, where I create three different skill objects:

```
def edit
    3.times{resource.skills.build}
    render_with_scope :edit
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<% counter = 0 %>
<%= f.fields_for :skills do |s|  %>
  <li>
    <%= s.label :name, "Skill #{counter}" %>
    <%= s.text_field :name %>
    <% counter = counter + 1 %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

It is preferred to use `s.label :name`, since that will make sure when you click the label, the text-box will get the focus. But the value of the label can be overruled, as i did here.

I am not quite sure what else you could mean with changing the label for each item, so if you could make that clearer.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just scope the label to `s`:

```
<%= f.field_for :skills do |s|  %>
<li>
  <%= s.label :name, 'Skills' %>
  <%= s.text_field :name %>
</li>
<% end %>
```

I think that should do it.